# add drop down menu to a burger menu C# UAP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uap

I want to add a drop down menu to this burger menu
so first you open the burger menu and when you click on settings for example that it will open an other drop down menu with items in it.

Xaml and C#:

```
  <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
           CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Background="Gray">
                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuButton1_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sales" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE825;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Marketing" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton3" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE115;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Settings" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton4" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE134;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Help" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SplitView Basic" FontSize="54" Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>

    private void HamburgerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySplitView.IsPaneOpen = !MySplitView.IsPaneOpen;
    }

    private void MenuButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```